# How does NextJS execute the code inside these functions with and without async?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, next.js, async-await

Function with `async`:

```
export async function getPostData(id) {
    const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, `${id}.md`);
    const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8');
    const matterResult = matter(fileContents);
    return {
        id,
        ...matterResult.data,
    };
}
```

Function without `async`:

```
export function getPostData(id) {
    const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, `${id}.md`);
    const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8');
    const matterResult = matter(fileContents);
    return {
        id,
        ...matterResult.data,
    };
}
```

I recently got back into NextJS and have forgotten how do these 2 functions would operate with and without async. I will try my best to explain them to see if I am correct:

The function without async will behave synchronously meaning that the constant "fullPath" will execute its function and will not continue to the next variable until it has finished.

The same for the rest of the variables.

The function with async (or asynchronous) will execute the function's variables at the same time.

However, in this situation, the variable "matterResult" depends on the variable "fileContents" to finish as this one is waiting on the variable "fullPath" to finish executing.

Can I execute this async function without "await" on the variables? What difference will it make? Do these behave in a synchronous way despite these variables being inside an async function?

Comment: Pictures of code are nowhere near as useful as the actual code.

Comment: `async` does not change how the function is run, *except* when an `await` is involved. It looks like your functions are the same except for `async`, so the differince is that the caller gets the result (whatever it is) and in the second it gets a Promise that will resolve to the result.

Comment: And `async` definitely does not mean that it runs statements in the function in parallel.

Comment: Should be more clear now.

Comment: All functions in both functions are synchronous. The `async` one returns a needless promise<Object> and the normal one returns an object. So at the receiving side there must be a `instanceOf Promise` check to fix the rest.

Comment: My question is more on how the variables inside each function will be executed, not on what will happen after their execution.

Comment: Again, there will be **no difference** between the non-`async` and `async` versions in the way the statements in the function are executed.

Comment: In these specific examples, yes. you are right. That is what I was trying to figure out. However, if there's 2 constant variables that are doing a fetch request, in async, these variables will execute at the same time and without async, the second execution will start as soon as the first one will finish. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The body of an async function can be thought of as being split by zero
> or more await expressions. Top-level code, up to and including the
> first await expression (if there is one), is run synchronously. **In
> this way, an async function without an await expression will run
> synchronously.** If there is an await expression inside the function
> body, however, the async function will always complete asynchronously.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score 0):

## NextJS

It executes both functions the same. It checks if the function returned `Promise` or not - it did - it will wait for its execution and use the fulfilled value as return value of the function (or pass the promise further if what it was doing was also asynchronous).

## Async simplified?

First correct async function would be like that

```
export async function getPostData(id) {
    const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, `${id}.md`);
    const fileContents = await fs.readFile(fullPath, 'utf8');
    const matterResult = matter(fileContents);
    return {
        id,
        ...matterResult.data,
    };
}
```

This function would be rewritten in JS using `Promise` - ((very very simplified rewrite, not actual one))

```
export function getPostData(id) {
  return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => { // async here, is just for showing how this is treated. Actual rewrite uses generators and state machine. This is only for simplification of example.
    try {  
       const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, `${id}.md`);
       const fileContents = await fs.readFile(fullPath, 'utf8');
       const matterResult = matter(fileContents);
       return resolve({
           id,
           ...matterResult.data,
       });
    } catch (err) { return reject(err); }
  });
}
```

As people in comments already told you, this functions are not really so different, and variables in them are behaving with theirs scopes. What is different is what is returned. `async` functions always returns `Promise` (or `PromiseLike`) object, normal functions not always. Also in `async` functions you can use `await`.

`async` and `await` together make asynchronous code execution written in a manner reassembling linear written code.

```
function async name() {
  await command1();
  await command2();
}
```

Normally would be written (using promises)

```
function name() {
  command1().then(() => {
    command2().then(() => {});
  });
}
```

Which, when you want to return some values, or pass them, or handle errors - can become very complicated code, but using `async&await` it becomes quite clear/clean.